# Help with installing Ubuntu from usb stick

Tags: usb-drive

I used my desktop computer to create a bootable usb drive on a 8gb flash drive. I placed the usb in my laptop, which has no current OS, and I received the following error:

```
syslinux 4.06 EDD 4.06-pre1 Copyright (C) 1994-2011 H. Peter Anvin et al EDD: Error 0100 reading sector 536872960
```

What is going on and what do I do now?

Comment: It appears your bootable USB drive is corrupt. Try recreating the bootable USB drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is make sure that you format your USB stick with a FAT32.

Download Ubuntu [32bit or 64bit](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Download [UnetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). UNetbootin allows for the installation of various Linux/Ubuntu distributions to a partition or USB drive, so you don't need a CD. Its available for Linux, Windows, and Mac OS X.

[Click here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) for information on How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows.

[Click here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) for information on How to create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was formatted to NTFS that was my problem.